# Strange .replace() behaviour in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="allownumericwithdecimal"/>saadad
</div>
```

```js
$(".allownumericwithdecimal").live("keypress keyup ", function (event) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (!((event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) || event.which == 8 || event.which == 46 || event.which == 110 || event.which == 0)) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.'), text.indexOf('.').length).length > 2)) {
            //event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    var text = $(this).val();
    if ((event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) && (text.indexOf('.') != -1)) {
        if ((text.substring(text.indexOf('.'), text.indexOf('.').length).length) > 2) {
            //event.preventDefault();
        }
        if (event.which == 190) {
            //event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    if (text.indexOf('.') != -1 && event.which == 190) {
        if (text.match("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$")) {} else {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }
    if (text.indexOf('.') == -1 && text.length > 7 && (event.which != 190 && event.which != 8 && event.which != 46 && event.which != 110 && event.which != 0)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx9h2smh/

The problem is If I type a value in textBox say 3434 and now I want to make it 35434 by putting cursor after 3 and pressing 5, it works fine in Firefox and IE but in chrome the 5 get added after value and it becomes 34345.

The culprit line is one which replace non numeric characters.

How to handle this issue??

Comment: Interesting, but test case unclear, add proper input values and what actual you want output.

Comment: Each time you press the keybord, it replace the value with a new one. So what you need is, to make a test before replacing the value of the `input` element.

Comment: @S͢kyD͢ream Thanks, I was in meeting during last one hour and issue is already resolved. Do I still need to add proper input and desired output values for future seekers??

Comment: @RishiPrakash no no I understsnd, well thanks good que. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `code`, it runs. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx9h2smh/2/)

I just do a test

```
if ( /[^0-9\.]/g.test($(this).val()) ) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'')); 
}
```

**Explain**

You just make sure that the user enter the value of what you want. You replace if the entered value is not an `integer`. Your regex mean: **"Those which are not integer or dot (.), replace them with an empty value"**. That why You need to make this test. Therefore, if the user enters the value you want, it doesn't do the action replace and it doesn't pass to the test.

Comment: I voted up your answer. It is not posted by me dude !!

Comment: I thought, you're the one who asked this question! thanks for the vote! :)

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina I was the one who posted this code :) Thanks for help.

Comment: @RishiPrakash It's a great pleasure to help you.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina can you please add theoretical explanation too for this, I mean how your code works?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina yes, Although I figured it out on my own too. :)

Comment: yeah, you almost did it, if you didn't forget the test! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".allownumericwithdecimal").live("keypress keyup ",function (event) {

    var caretP= $(this).getCursorPosition();
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'')); 
 var text = $(this).val();        
   
 if (!((event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) || event.which ==8 || event.which ==46 || event.which ==110 || event.which ==0) )
 {
  var text = $(this).val();
  if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.'), text.indexOf('.').length).length > 2)) {
   //event.preventDefault();
  }       
 } 
 var text = $(this).val(); 
 if((event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) &&  (text.indexOf('.') != -1))
 { 
  if((text.substring(text.indexOf('.'), text.indexOf('.').length).length)>2)
  {
   //event.preventDefault();
  }
  if(event.which==190)
  {
   //event.preventDefault();
  }
 }
 if(text.indexOf('.') != -1 && event.which==190 )
 { 
  if(text.match("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$")){
  }
  else{
   $(this).val('') ;
  }
 }
  if(text.indexOf('.') == -1 && text.length>7 && (event.which!=190 && event.which !=8 && event.which !=46 && event.which !=110 && event.which !=0)){
   event.preventDefault();
  }
    
    $(this).selectRange(caretP,caretP);
    
});




(function($) {
    
    $.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
    
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        var input = this.get(0);
        if (!input) return; // No (input) element found
        if (document.selection) {
            // IE
           input.focus();
        }
        return 'selectionStart' in input ? input.selectionStart:'' || Math.abs(document.selection.createRange().moveStart('character', -input.value.length));
     }
   })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="allownumericwithdecimal"/>saadad
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah nicely working. but extra code for cursor position. :(

Note : Question has not asked by me.

Answer (score 0):

`kepress` seems to be the culprit when I changed the fiddle to just use `keyup` the replacement happened correctly (though the cursor shifted to the end)

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx9h2smh/1/

Comment: cursor must not shift to end.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the 'keypress' event keypress event is very similar to the keydown event. If you press a button keypress event cannot identify the character. In your code it takes as current input Empty so it replace the character.